# Is it correct to insert strings in Jinja2 as javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, string, jinja2

I have a Flask app with Jinja2 templates. I decided to move all strings (static text that I want to display on the web page) from templates to the separate javascript file. This file is loaded in layout.html and I am inserting strings as

`<script>document.write(home_call_to_action['card_text']);</script>`

Is there any better way to do that, if I want to make them better readable? (w/o

Mb something like:

```
{% set print = <script>document.write({{ text }});</script> %}

<b>{{ print.home_call_to_action['card_text'] }}<b>
```

if it possible to pass one variable into another somehow/

Comment: what are these strings?

Comment: static text that I want to display on the web page

Comment: static text should not displayed with javascript! Using `document.write` isn't a good idea either.

Comment: are you looking for something like «Flask Babel»?

Comment: No, I am not interested in localization. I just want to have all strings in the separate file and I want to load them on client side, if it is possible ofc

Comment: So the answer is: No it is not correct to use javascript for static text. Use the template engine.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting scripts as strings will work, but is not the "correct" way to do it.
What you should do is put all the scripts in the static directory and link to them in  your layout.html with

```
<script src="path/to/script" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and make sure nothing is between `<script></script>` tags.

**EDIT**

I see what you want to do. To display python strings in a template you need to pass them as an argument to `render_template()` function. And then just put the string inside `{{  }}` tags in your template.

[Check the step 5 and step 6 of the official flask tutorial.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/views/)

You should also check [the official Jinja2 docs.](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/)

Comment: That is what I have allready. The question is about how to display them?